# Using Returned SQL Data in command line, and ultimately winforms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Essentially what I want to do is request rows from an sql server and make use of the data it returns.

```
SELECT customer, postcode FROM all_customers WHERE hometown = london
```

I then want to first print all of the returned fields using `Console.WriteLine` and then assign the values in each of the rows to variables for further manipulation.

I have a string below which appears to compile fine, however when it comes to running the program, I do not seem to be able to interact with any data returned, if indeed any is returned at all.  I have tried a number of solutions with no success.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Connection String");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SQL Query";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the records, returned by the call to `ExecuteReader()`.

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    // Loop through the records
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Get value in columns 1 and 2, assuming they're a string and int
        var someValue = reader.GetString(0);
        var someId = reader.GetInt32(1);

        // Or get by the column name:
        var someValue = reader["some_column"].ToString();
        var someId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["another_column"]);
    }
}
```